# Sticky navbar and container scroll

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a `sticky-top` `navbar`. I want the `scrollbar` to start scrolling inside the `container` and not the `body`, because when some other page is shorter and there's no scrollbar the items in the navbar move on the right (for the width of a scrollbar).

How do I need to change the html or CSS?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tw5msvq8/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `overflow: auto` on your container. But it only works if you set the `height` too!

I guess you want to stretch the container to full height. So the easiest way is to define a variable for the navbar height and calculate the container's height. Add this code to your css:

```
:root {
    --navbar-height: 56px;
}
.navbar {
    height: var(--navbar-height);
}
.container {
    overflow: auto;
    height: calc(100vh - (var(--navbar-height)));
}
```